# Put an order to the result of $http requests in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have 3 web requests that do through $http, this petition are in functions (`function1()`, `function2()`, `function3()`) . I would like to customize the order in which all these requests are executed.

```
object.function1().then(function() {
//result of petition $http of function1();
});

object.function2().then(function() {
//result of petition $http of function1();
});

object.function3().then(function() {
//result of petition $http of function2();
});
```

they all try to run at the same time. some requests take longer than others because they get more JSON objects. I want to run in order to start by:

```
function1();  //first
function2();  //second
function3();  //three
```

Comment: Call them in `.then` handler..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call the functions inside the other function's callback like this:

```
object.function1().then(function() {
    //result of petition $http of function1();

    object.function2().then(function() {
        //result of petition $http of function1();

        object.function3().then(function() {
            //result of petition $http of function2();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: You should avoid the "tower of doom": https://gist.github.com/sumtraveller/2a42b930dba2375c331e

Answer (score 5):

You need to make proper use of the `.then()` method:

```
object.function1().then(function(result) {
    //result of petition $http of function1();

    return object.function2()
}).then(function (result) {
    //result of petition $http of function2();

    return object.function3();
}).then(function (result) {
    //result of petition $http of function3();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this.

```
$http.get('URL1').success(function(data){
    $http.get('URL2').success(function(data){
        $http.get('URL3').success(function(data){
            console.log('Done');
        }
    }
});
```